# In Typescript, can I constrain the type of the value at a generic key?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

In Typescript, how can I constrain the type a field on a generic type to a particular type? In other words, I want to write a function that accepts an object `obj` and a key `key` of that object, but raises a Typescript error if `obj[key]` is not of type `X`. For instance, if `X` is `string`:

```
function foo<T extends {}, K extends keyof T ???>(obj: T, key: K) { 
  console.log(obj[key])
}

>> foo({ fox: 'Mulder' }, 'fox')
Mulder

>> foo({ fox: 22 }, 'fox')
<some error here>
```

Answer (score 2):

Guerric's answer demonstrates how type parameters are *usually* constrained: 1) define `T` constrained to be an object, then 2) define `K` constrained to be a key of `T`.

For the OP's case, however, I would reverse this logic: 1) define `Key` constrained to be a generic property key (a.k.a `string | number | symbol`), then 2) define `Obj` constrained to be an object containing property `Key`:

```
function foo<Key extends PropertyKey, Obj extends Record<Key, string>>(obj: Obj, key: Key) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}

foo({ fox: 'Mulder' }, 'fox'); // works fine

foo({ fox: 22 }, 'fox'); // Error (number is not assignable to string)
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/wOzr6W)*.

This way, you get readable errors (in this context, **"number is not assignable to string"** is much less confusing than "string is not assignable to never"), and also the implementation of the function (the `console.log(obj[key])` bit) does not require any typecasting since `obj` is properly typed to have a `Key` key.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
function foo<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: T[K] extends string ? T[K] : never) { 
  console.log((obj as any)[key]);
}

foo({ fox: 'Mulder' }, 'fox'); // OK


foo({ fox: 22 }, 'fox'); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
```

It implies to cast `obj as any` in the implementation because `never` can't be used as an index type, even though [nothing is assignable to `never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) so a function call with an actual `key` parameter that would make `key` type resolve to `never` will never compile (by definition), but TypeScript is not clever enough to infer that.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEBvAXwBpEBpHfQ0xAa2wE85hEMA+ABRwARgCsAXL1rsOkjAG06AXUYFiZElABOMMAHNEAfl6KVksNgBu2LQEoKiALAAoRIggIScADbYAdN5wegJCYogAhmThYBy28jJKtgDcLpQuLihwAuTIcLiSAOQAsiDeRDYFiDSIBSi4Bcnpzhmo2bn5iABMnVW0tXkNSUA)